# Can't go through a Haskell tutorial

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, cabal

I'm quite new to Haskell – I know its syntax and not really much more, so I assumed the best way to get a bit more information is to follow some tutorials from Haskell wiki.

I found this one:
https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program

Unfortunatelly, when I reach item (2.9), my results diverge from what's shown on the website. When I type `cabal install --enable-tests`, I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring haq-0.1.0.0...
Building haq-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'haq' for haq-0.1.0.0...
Linking dist/dist-sandbox-2a06ecba/build/haq/haq ...
Preprocessing test suite 'tests' for haq-0.1.0.0...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id haq-0.1.0.0-inplace
    (use -v for more information)
Failed to install haq-0.1.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haq-0.1.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

There are really two questions:

1. How can I solve this problem and make it compile?
2. Where does this `-inplace` appended to my package's version come from? I tried adding it in cabal file, but that didn't help either.

I'll be happy to post more details if needed. My code is pretty much the same as the instructions in the tutorial say.

#### EDIT

Here's my `.cabal` file:

```
name:                haq
version:             0.1.0.0
description:         Super cool mega lambdas
license:             GPL
author:              Alojzy Leszcz
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable haq
  main-is:             Haq.hs  
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9  
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  
test-suite tests
  ghc-options:         -Wall
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:             HSpecTests.hs
  build-depends:       base,
                       haq,
                       hspec >= 1.8
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Comment: Please post your `.cabal` file.

Comment: Answer updated with a link to the full cabal file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `haq` in the `build-depends` section refers to a library, but your .cabal file does not specify how to build a library - ie. it doesn' have a `library` section.

You'll see what the `library` section should look like in section 3.2 of that wiki page: [(link)](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program#The_Cabal_file)

Comment: OK - I see what's the problem about, but the cabal file in the section 3.2 referes to another file. What I could do is to extract the content of the haq.hs file into a module and then try to run the example. I'll give it a try - thanks fr the help.

Obviously something must have changed since the tutorial was published. Is it that e.g. executables are no longer allowed in tests or what ? (forgive me potential wrong wording - as I said, I'm new to Haskell).

Comment: Looks like an edit made on May 29th 2014 added the `test-suite` section to the .cabal file with the reference to the `haq` library without first explaining how to define the library.

Comment: Makes sense. So in order to go through this tutorial, I'd need to: 
1.) Restructure the code: extract the functionality into a module.
2.) Add "library" section to my .cabal file.
3.) Use the newly created module in both executable and tests.
Right ?

Comment: Yes - that's what's done later on in the tutorial in section 3.

Answer (score 0):

OK - managed to come up with the valid configuration. Thanks for the hint.

Here's my cabal file:

```
-- Initial haq.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further documentation, 
-- see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                main
version:             0.1.0.0
license:             GPL-2
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Bogdan Baranski
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9
  exposed-modules:     Main
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable main
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base >=4.8 && <4.9
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite tests
  ghc-options:         -Wall
  default-extensions:  OverloadedStrings
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:             HSpecTests.hs
  build-depends:       base,
                       main,
                       hspec >= 1.8
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Also, I had to rename file to "Main.hs" in order to make it consistent with the module defined inside (I noticed that Haskell is very sensitive about this convention: a module "Module" must be defined in a file "Module.hs").